# GridView cannot find field in defined type, but anonymous type?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, gridview

I'm using LINQ to query data from database and then bind it to a GridView. When I use anonymous type, everything is OK, but now I want to reuse the data (for later filter), so I created a class to map the anonymous type, here it is:

```
public class DetailComplaint
{
    public decimal Id;
    public decimal Status;
    public string Name;
    public decimal ServiceId;
    public string Service;
    public string Title;
    public string Customer;
    public string Description;
    public DateTime CreatedDate;
    public decimal CreatedBy;
    public string Author;
    public decimal? AssignedBy;
    public decimal? AssignedTo;
    public string Technician;
    public DateTime? AssignedDate;
    public string Contact;
}
```

and then use it in the query (...select new DetailComplaint { //all fields are as same as before })

but now when I bind data, the GridView throws an exception that it can't find a field or property named "Id", which is explicitly defined in DetailComplaint.

How can I fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making these into properties instead of fields?  Some forms of binding will only work with properties and ignore fields.  It's unclear which `GridView` you are using but this is possibly the problem.

The easiest way to do that here is to use auto-properties like so

```
public class DetailComplaint
{
    public decimal Id {get; set; }
    public decimal Status {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public decimal ServiceId {get; set; }
    public string Service {get; set; }
    public string Title {get; set; }
    public string Customer {get; set; }
    public string Description {get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get; set; }
    public decimal CreatedBy {get; set; }
    public string Author {get; set; }
    public decimal? AssignedBy {get; set; }
    public decimal? AssignedTo {get; set; }
    public string Technician {get; set; }
    public DateTime? AssignedDate {get; set; }
    public string Contact {get; set; }
}
```